# How to use custom html tags to tell scripts where to put html?

Tags: javascript, html

I built a plugin which is loaded with an external script, it basically contains some buttons and widgets that users may want to place in their body.

However I'm not sure how they can tell the plugin where to put the buttons from the plugin, I noticed facebook does something with a custom tag for their like and login plugins:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true"></fb:login-button>
```

What other options are there? How can I replace an element like this one with my button's html?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('fb:login-button')` or `$('fb\\:login-button')`?

Comment: somehow I don't think this tag will reach the client and not be preprocessed by the server. What server technology are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Have your users create markup like this.  They can use a span if it needs to be an inline control.

```
<div data-yourPluginName="typeOfControl"></div>
```

Then have your plugin replace that markup like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-yourPluginName]').each(function() {
        var controlType = $(this).attr('data-yourPluginName');
        var replaceThis = $(this);

        if(controlType === 'foo') {
            // transform 'replaceThis' into a 'foo'
        } else if( controlType === 'bar' ) {
            // make it a 'bar'
        }
    });
});
```

If you really want to use a custom tag the code is similar:

```
//instead of:
$('[data-yourPluginName]').each(function() {

// simply use:
$('customTag1, customTag2').each(function() {
    var controlType = $(this).prop('tagName'); // this will be CUSTOMTAG1 in capitals
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not that familiar with using custom tags.  With the new HTML5 spec and 'data-' prefixed attributes it just seemed like it would be guaranteed not to cause issues and avoid any further includes like XML document type definitions, etc.  The same replacement code should work with custom tags with a few tweaks, I'll edit.

Comment: anks, I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to pack jQuery with my plugin. I think it may be "nicer" to make the plugin with plain js so as not to force jQuery on them. I'll look up how to do this with plain js, I just want an opinion.